# Link with self-compiled static libraries with cmake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I try to write some tests for project. If I need some project files I write `include_directories` statement and all will be included. In case of need of some manually compiled static libraries I try to set `target_link_libraries`.

If I set absolute path then all links ok, but for task I need another way to link another libraries, because the relative path to libraries gives undefined references.

In this case everything works fine:

```
target_link_libraries(ConsoleDumperTest GTest::GTest GTest::Main PocoFoundation PocoUtil PocoNet ${YAML_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(ConsoleDumperTest /home/yrusinov/projects/build-fleetd-2-Desktop-dbg/protocols/libprotocols.a)
target_link_libraries(ConsoleDumperTest /home/yrusinov/projects/build-fleetd-2-Desktop-dbg/consumers/libconsumers.a)
target_link_libraries(ConsoleDumperTest /home/yrusinov/projects/build-fleetd-2-Desktop-dbg/consumers/Console/libconsole.a)
```

but if I do:

```
target_link_libraries(ConsoleDumperTest GTest::GTest GTest::Main PocoFoundation PocoUtil PocoNet ${YAML_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(ConsoleDumperTest ../../../protocols/libprotocols.a)
target_link_libraries(ConsoleDumperTest ../../../consumers/libconsumers.a)
target_link_libraries(ConsoleDumperTest ../../../consumers/Console/libconsole.a)
```

I receive undefined references, despite of libraries contains in there directories. Which way I have to set path to link libraries?

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/target_link_libraries.html), `target_link_libraries` is not expected to work with *relative* paths: you should use either an **absolute** path, or a library **name**.

By knowing relative path, it is easy to construct absolute path in CMake. E.g., assuming you know relative path to the current source directory (the directory contained currently executed `CMakeLists.txt`), use *CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR* variable:

```
target_link_libraries(ConsoleDumperTest
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../protocols/libprotocols.a
)
```

Answer (score 1):

CMake's link_directories(...) command provides this:

> link_directories(directory1 directory2 ...)
>
> Specify the paths in which the linker should search for libraries. The command will apply only to targets created after it is called. Relative paths given to this command are interpreted as relative to the current source directory, see CMP0015.

Note also that, if these library dependencies are defined within the same CMake project, using `add_library(target_name ...)`, you may specify the target name instead of the binary name within `target_link_libraries`.